# Program displays strange characters on the screen

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I'm developing a client-server program, and this is my server_2 file, who will comunicate with the main server. 
The program displays on the screen these lines when is running. I think that those lines after the mkfifo are causing this.

```
i�e|楬���h�.N=��.8��
i�H��h� ��h� �i���Ǭ��ǬjǬ�dǬ�@��i�P@h�Ǭ���h����h�jǬ��ǬP
```

Structures

```
typedef struct request req;
struct request
{
    char str[256];
    int client_pid;
    int login; // In case of client, to identify if is logged
    int whois; // To identify who is the client and the server
};

typedef struct answer ans;
struct answer
{
    char str[256];
    int server_pid;
    int type;
    int login;
    int num_users;
};
```

Main:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fifo_1, fifo_2;
    struct request req;
    struct answer ans;

    if(argc == 2) // Check if the command was well prompted
    {
        if(strcasecmp(argv[1], "show") == 0 || strcasecmp(argv[1], "close") == 0)
        {
            if(fifo_2 = open("FIFO_SERV", O_WRONLY) == -1) 
            {
                perror("[SERVER_2] Error: on the FIFO_SERVER opening!\n");
                sleep(2);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if(mkfifo("FIFO_SERV_2", 0777) == -1) 
            {
                perror("[SERVER_2] Error: on the FIFO_SERVER_2 creation!\n");
                sleep(2);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            strcpy(req.str, argv[1]); // Copy the argumento to the structure

            write(fifo_2, &req, sizeof(req)); // Write a request to the server
            strcpy(req.str,""); // Clean the string

            fifo_1 = open("FIFO_SERV_2", O_RDONLY); 

            read(fifo_1, &ans, sizeof(ans)); //Read an answ
        }

    //close(fifo_1);
    unlink("FIFO_SERVER_2");
    sleep(2);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: You havent given us enough code... Like the structs, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The precedence rules of operators `=` and `==` make the line

```
if(fifo_2 = open("FIFO_SERV", O_WRONLY) == -1)
```

equivalent to

```
if(fifo_2 = (open("FIFO_SERV", O_WRONLY) == -1))
```

which essentially assigns 0 to fifo_2 if `open` succeeds and 1 if `open` fails. The values 0 and 1 also happens to be the respective values of the standard input and output file descriptor in POSIX standard library implementations (see [File descriptor on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)), so later when you execute

```
write(fifo_2, &req, sizeof(req)); // Write a request to the server
```

you are either trying to write to standard input (undefined behavior), or to standard output depending on whether the file could be opened rather than to the server. To fix this, you can replace the open expression with:

```
if((fifo_2 = open("FIFO_SERV", O_WRONLY)) == -1)
```

Then, you may have to figure out why you can't open the file (since you are presumably writing to standard output, which means `open` failed).

Comment: Thank's for the tip SleuthEye, it's not printing the strange characters! Actually, now the program is not doing anything. Just don't do nothing after i start to run it.